Nonhomogeneus PDE function requires expansion in sines?
I'm studying about the solution to the PDE:
$$
\Delta u(x,y)=-f(x,y)\\ u(0,y)=u(a,y)=0 \\ u(x,0)=g(x) \ \ , \ \ u(x,b)=h(x)
$$
And the first step is to start solving it like a homogeneus equation with separation of variables and get to a solution of the form:
$$
u(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\text{sin}(\frac{\pi n}{a}x)Y_n(y)
$$
If we now plug that proposed solution into the nonhomogeneus PDE we get:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\ddot{Y}_n(y)-\alpha_n^2Y_n(y))\text{sin}(\alpha_nx)=-f(x,y) $$
The next step is to expand $f(x,y)$ into series of $\text{sin}(\alpha_nx)$ like this:
$$ f(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(y)\text{sin}(\alpha_nx) $$
Where:
$$ f(y)= \frac{2}{a}\int_0^a f(x,y)\text{sin}(\alpha_nx) $$
Now I have two questions. First is how are we sure that sinuses are gonna be enough for expanding $-f(x,y)$ into the sum we plugged into the PDE? The only reason we got rid of the cosines was because of the initial conditions imposed on $X(x)=A\text{cos}(\alpha x)+B\text{sin}(\alpha x)$ and it was only for the homogeneus version of the equation. The second question is the exact same but about the expansion of $f(x,y)$ with coefficiens $f(y)$. As far as I understand to expand ANY function into such trigonometric series you need both the sine and the cosine and with only the sime we can reconstruct only odd functions. Is it the case that because of the initial conditions $f(x,y)$ has to be odd wrt $x$? That is the only solution I can think about but I dont understand why would it be true.

We know sines are the correct expansion basis because this family of sines were the solution to the $X$ equation in separation of variables:
$$
X'' + \lambda X = 0, \ X(0) = X(a) = 0.
$$
This is a regular Sturm-Liouville problem and it is well-known that the solutions to such a problem form a complete orthogonal basis for the space of square-integrable functions, $L^2([0,a])$. This means that any sufficiently regular function on $[0,a]$ can be uniquely represented as an infinte sine series. If we had a more exotic equation here, we would get a different sequence of functions that may not be trig functions (e.g. Bessel functions) but we would still use those to expand the function and find its coefficients using the same procedure.
